# what would be the most efficient method to track changes in files?

Tags: java, file

I've read an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041018/5899042) that states that it's possible to create a change-notification in a database by writing the changes to an external file monitorized by an intended java program.

So, my question is what would be the most efficient and with better performance way to track changes made on an external file?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice?

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Comment: Thanks... also, is there any mechanism to retrieve the latest changes instead of reading the whole file?