# Database Polling and Scheduling in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, polling

I need to perform Polling operation on one of the DB table(say T1) and update status on another DB table(say T2). This Job has to be scheduled whenever there is an insertion in the Table T2.

I am aware of Quartz scheduler but that gives time based scheduling and polling.
Are there any other libraries which would be handy for such cases?

Comment: Can you specify how the DB is updated? Is the insert coming from your application or is it coming from another source?

Comment: Quartz allows you create a Job dynamically and executes it "now". Not sure why you need do it with a "polling approach", I mean, why do not you update the second table "inside" the request that updates the first one?. On the other hand, maybe you can manage that situation with a database trigger.

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem you're trying to solve and any constraints on the solution.  In general, polling is not a desired solution because often it wastes resources. I would try for an event based solution first.  Have you considered adding a SQL insert trigger on T1? It could do an update of T2. This would avoid the extra work/complexity of running a task scheduler.  If you must use polling, I believe Quartz has a rich feature set with many scheduling modes.  If you don't like Quartz, Java has several thread pool executors that might work, such as ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @doctore Yeah trigger can be one of the solution, but the DB is not under my control and also the same tables are used for multiple purpose so making a generic polling mechanism was what I thought of.

Comment: @devdanke Yeah you are right. So what I am trying to achieve is once there is a row inserted in T2, I need to check status Column  for any change inT1 table and keep checking it for 1 minute, and if there was any change detected in that column, then I will need to update the value of inserted row in T2.

Comment: @aeberhart Yep, the update and insertion are taking place from my application itself.

Answer (score 2):

In principle there are two approaches to your problem:

1. *Get an immediate notification when a change occurs*:
   This means that either the database tells you about the change (via a DB trigger) or the application that makes the change tells you about it.
   You said that triggers are not an option, since the DB is not under your control. You also said that the change originates in our application. So a possible solution could be to have the code that makes the change notify other modules about the change. One possibility could be to allow registering a callback / handler method. This pattern is very common, for example when you register an onClick handler on a UI button. You are saying "whenever this happens, call me" (see for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setAction(javax.swing.Action)).
2. *Poll for the change*:
   This method is less effective / more resource intensive but can be applied when option 1) is not possible (DB trigger not possible, changes happen through another (part of the) application you do not control). You simply keep looking for the change in regular intervals. You can use Quartz for this or also the built in classes like java.util.TimerTask / java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: I would like to get some clarity on this resolution please - is there a similar approach that I can adopt when an insertion occurs on a table, resulting in my Java framework or function being called? I unfortunately cannot come up with a solution but I have decided to use a trigger in MySQL but I would now like to call my Java Function from the trigger, is this possible can you point me to some article please?

Comment: The trigger is an event inside the DB engine. So from there, you could communicate back to your Java process. Assuming your application has a web service interface (e.g. via JAX-RS), this could be done by running an HTTP client like curl or wget. Using MySQL, there seems to be sys_exec user defined function (https://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) that could be used. So the trigger starts a process and runs curl, curl makes an HTTP request to your Java service and finally a REST endpoint can call your event handler.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, I will look into this right away. I don't have a webservice interface but If its requires me to add one I will do so

Comment: Maybe check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041018/13791091. It suggests using a named pipe as a means of communication.